# Can this C++ method be simplified?

Tags: c++, algorithm, debugging, c++14

Background:

I have been implementing the [gap buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) algorithm as an STL container with matching custom iterator.  The Buffer class has amongst other members, two internal pointers `_gapStart` and `_gapEnd` which represent the start and the end of the gap respectively.

The `BufferIterator` has two members `_buffer` which is a reference to the Buffer class it is iterating over and `_pos` which is the current position in the Buffer.  What makes it different from a normal iterator is that as it moves backwards and forwards through the buffer, it should "skip over" the gap.

To this end I have the code below which implements `operator+=` (all the other iterator arithmetic operators are defined in terms of it). This code works but I have a nagging feeling it could be made simpler.

```
BufferIterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n) {
   auto count = n;

   if (count >= 0) {
        while (count--) {
            ++_pos;
            if (_pos == _buffer._gapStart) {
                _pos += (_buffer._gapEnd - _buffer._gapStart);
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (count++) {
            --_pos;
            if (_pos == _buffer._gapEnd) {
                _pos -= (_buffer._gapEnd - _buffer._gapStart);
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

So I want to replace it with the version below.  However it doesn't work; it causes a segfault.  Why?  It seems to me it should be completely equivalent and I can't figure out why it isn't.

```
BufferIterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n) {

    if (n >= 0) {
        _pos += n;
        if (_pos >= b._gapStart) {
            _pos += (b._gapEnd - b._gapStart);
        }
    } else {
        _pos -= n;
        if (_pos <= b._gapEnd) {
            _pos -= (b._gapEnd - b._gapStart);
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand this? Is there any simpler way of implementing version 1 or is it truly the best way of implementing it?

Btw if it helps to see the code in context, my simple editor can be found [on Github](https://github.com/jaldhar/editor).

Comment: @PaulRooney the code for the classes as a whole was posted on codereview and I got valuable feedback but not for this bit.  I asked here rather than there because in part I want to understand why the two versions are not equivalent and I thought that kind of question is more in SOs bailiwick.

Comment: There is a bug in your second version. Think about `_gapStart = 2; _gapEnd = 4; pos = 10;n= 10;` What should the new pos be now? PS this is the kind of thing unit tests should catch.

Comment: In the first example, shouldn't there be a break statement after the `_pos += (_buffer._gapEnd - _buffer._gapStart);`? Unless you are iterating over multiple buffers? Not obvious with your current code

Comment: @smac89 There was a missing ) which I've fixed which may have led you to think that but no, a break isn't needed.

Comment: @LokiAstari Thanks to Jarod42 I see what the problem is.  Point taken about unit tests.  I'm a professional developer but only a hobbyist in C++. I do little projects like these to keep my skills sharp but I don't know all the pro tools yet.  I'm going to look into unit testing frameworks when I get the chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First version can be simplified like that:

```
BufferIterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n) {
   auto count = n;

   if (count >= 0) {
        while (count--) {
            ++_pos;
            if (_pos == _buffer._gapStart) {
                _pos = _buffer._gapEnd;
            }
        }
    } else {
        while (count++) {
            --_pos;
            if (_pos == _buffer._gapEnd) {
                _pos = _buffer._gapStart;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

And to remove the loop, your code may look like:

```
BufferIterator& operator+=(const difference_type& n) {
    if (n >= 0) {
        if (_pos < b._gapStart && b._gapStart <= _pos + n) {
            _pos += b._gapEnd - b._gapStart;
        }
    } else {
        if (_pos + n <= b._gapEnd && b._gapEnd < _pos) {
            _pos -= (b._gapEnd - b._gapStart);
        }
    }
    _pos += n;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used your second version.  I made one small optimization I removed the last line of each if/else block and replaced it with `_pos += n;` before the return.

Comment: @Jaldhar, just to make sure: `_pos += n` before the return isn't equivalent to what you originally had in your question. Your original code (and, consequently, Jarod42's code) caused `_pos` to increase regardless of the sign of `n`, because if `n >= 0`, you added `n`, otherwise you subtracted `n`, but `n` is a negative number, so you added `abs(n)`. With this optimization that you made, you decrease `pos` in the second case. If that's what you expect, fine, but just wanted to draw your attention to this detail.

Comment: @FreeNickname yes that was the expected behavior.  Looks like I really wasn't thinking straight when I originally wrote that code!

Comment: @Jaldhar it happens :)